# Argparse: "-p" or "-p=value" but not "-p value"

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to add an argument that is only usable as `-p` or `-p=value`, but not `-p value`

I want to add an optional argument `--parallel/-p` to the script. Here is how I want user to pass it:

```
./script arg1 arg2 -p    # this defaults to 10
./script arg1 arg2 -p=13 # This is fine and will set the value to 13
./script arg1 arg2 -p 13 # This is NOT fine and I want to ban this. Next line will tell why.
./script -p arg1 arg2    # I want -p to be usable regardless of its position. 
# But here arg1 will be considered as an argument of -p option, which is unwanted.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have two problems here :

- `argparse` only allow `--option=value` for long argument, which are generated when the name is longer than one character.
- `argparse` give no way to enforce the `--option=value` syntax, and `--option value` will always be possible.

You may have to write your own parser using what is inside `sys.args` (if you only have one option, it can be done quickly by searching the argument starting with `"-p"`.